# Attempt to proof the Cantor-Bernstein theorem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I've found a proof of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem in Kleene's 'Introduction to Metamathematics' (1952) in §4 Thm A. I must admit I don't understand its essence but I was wondering if the proof could be formulated like this:

**Theorem.** Given two injections $f_M:M \rightarrow N$ and $f_N:N \rightarrow M$. Then there exists a bijection $f:M \rightarrow N$.

**Proof.** If there exists a bijection $f$ it has to have the following two properties:
(i) $(\forall m_1,m_2 \in M)\: m_1 \neq m_2 \rightarrow f(m_1) \neq f(m_2)$ 
(ii) $(\forall n \in N)(\exists m \in M) \: n = f(m)$ 

(i) holds since $f_M$ is injective. 
Concerning (ii): If $n \in f_M(M)$, then there is an $m \in M$ such that $n = f_M(m)$. If $n \notin f_M(M)$ then there is an $m \in M$ such that $n = f_N^{-1}(m)$. 

So what about
$$ f = \left\{ \begin{align} f_M & \qquad \text{if} \: n \in f_M(M) \\ f_N^{-1} & \qquad \text{otherwise}. \end{align}\right. $$

Comment: Take care for (i). There is no reason for the bijection $f$ to be equal to $f_M$. And also $f_N$ might not be invertible.

Comment: How do you know that every element of $M$ is either in $F_M^{-1}(N)$ or $f_N(N)$? If not, you haven't defined $f$ for all values.

Comment: What you write makes little sense... $f_M^{-1}(N) = M$. Maybe you mean $f_M(M)$? You should correct your question...

Comment: Also, $F_M^{-1}(N)=M$ by default. If $f:X\to Y$ then $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ always.

Comment: He can't mean $f_M(M)$, @EmanuelePaolini, because he needs to define $f$ on $M$.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx: I agree that there's no reason for $f$ to be equal to $f_M$, but from my definition this is just the case for $n \in f_M(M)$. My assumption that $f_N$ is invertible is wrong of course. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You're right. I can't tell if every element of $M$ has a corresponding element in $N$. I really need to delve into one of those ready-made proofs available..

Comment: It's a non-trivial theorem. In particular, as is noted on the wikipedia page, there is no 'constructive' proof - which means you can't prove it without either a proof by contradiction or some non-constructive axiom like the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Test your solution with $M=N=\mathbb N$, $f_M(n) = n+1$, $f_N(n) = 2n$.

Comment: Got it. In case of $n = 1$, $f_M$ applies and the corresponding element would be $m = 0$. If $n = 0$, we would get $f_N^{-1}(0) = \frac{0}{2} = 0$, resulting in $f$ to not be surjective. Thank you for the editing remark by the way. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Motivated by the counterexample given by Emanuele Paolini here comes a design rule for a correspondence given by Bernstein (1897) that can be proven having injective and surjective property [Kleene, 1952]:

> Consider any element $m$ of $M$. Either $m$ belongs to the subset $A$, or $m$ does not belong to $A$, i.e. $m$ belongs to $M-A$. If $m$ belongs to $A$, the corresponding element $n$ of $N$ shall be that which corresponds to $m$ in the correspondence $M \stackrel{1}{\sim} N_1$. If $m$ belongs to $M-A$ (in which case $m$ belongs to $M_1$), the corresponding element $n$ of $N$ shall be that to which $m$ corresponds in the correspondence $N \stackrel{2}{\sim} M_1$.

Following is an attempt of proving why a correspondence based on the rules of Bernstein have injective and surjective properties.

Firstly, the subset $A$ needs to be defined (recursively):
$$ A_0 := M \setminus f_N(N), \qquad A_{\alpha+1} := f_N(f_M(A_{\alpha})), \qquad \alpha = 0,1,2,3,..., \qquad A := \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}} A_{\alpha}, $$
where $f_N$ is the injection from $N$ to $M$ and $f_M$ is the injection from $M$ to $N$.

Similarly, we set $B$ to be the set
$$ B_{\alpha+1} := f_M(A_{\alpha}), \qquad B:=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}\setminus 0} B_{\alpha}. $$

Given two elements $m_1$ and $m_2$ in $A$. According to rule (i) the corresponding element to $m_1$ is $n_1 = f_M(m_1)$ and the corresponding element of $m_2$ is $n_2 = f_M(m_2)$. Since $f_M$ is injective, we have 
$$ (\forall m_1, m_2 \in M) \: m_1 \neq m_2 \rightarrow f_M(m_1) \neq f_M(m_2). $$
Now given two elements $m_1$ and $m_2$ not in $A$, i.e. $m_1, m_2 \in M \setminus A$. According to rule (ii), the corresponding element to $m_1$ is the element in $N$ such that $f_N(n_1) = m_1$. While the corresponding element to $m_2$ is the element $n_2$ in $N$ such that $f_N(n_2) = m_2$. If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are distinct we have, from the definition of a function
$$ (\forall n_1, n_2 \in N) \: f_N(n_1) \neq f_N(n_2) \rightarrow n_1 \neq n_2. $$
What if $m_1 \in A$ and $m_2 \in M \setminus A$? 
 

From the definition of $B_{\alpha + 1}$ we have that
$$ B \supseteq B_{\alpha + 1} := f_M(A_\alpha) = \{ f_M(m) : m \in A_{\alpha} \} \stackrel{(i)}{\ni} n_1$$
and since $m_1 \in A \rightarrow (\exists \alpha) \: m_1 \in A_{\alpha}$, it is true that there is a corresponding element $n_1$ to $m_1$ and it's in $B$. If, in turn, $m_2 \in M\setminus A$, the corresponding element $n_2$ in $N$ is, from rule (ii), exactly that element which maps on $m_2$: $f_N(n_2) = m_2$. By definition $A_{\alpha + 1} := f_N(B_{\alpha + 1})$, $f_N(N) \cap A_0 = \emptyset $ and $f_N$ being injective, $n_2$ must not be in $B$. 

Having covered all the possible permutations of two elements $m_1, m_2 \in M$, we conclude that 
$$ (\forall m_1, m_2 \in M) \: m_1 \neq m_2 \rightarrow n_1 \neq n_2. $$
This requires the correspondence b/w $M$ and $N$, given by rule (i) and (ii), to be injective. 

For the correspondence $(i) \wedge (ii)$ to be bijective, it needs to have surjective property as well. I.e. every element in $N$ needs to have a corresponding element in $M$. Given an arbitrary element $n \in B$, there will be a corresponding element in $A \subseteq M$ due to the injection $B_{\alpha + 1} := f_M(A_{\alpha})$ and (i). Now if $n \in N \setminus B$, according to rule (ii), there is a corresponding element $M\setminus A \ni m = f_N(N \setminus B)$ because of $A_{\alpha + 1} := f_N(B_{\alpha + 1})$ and $f_N$ being an injection. 

This finally gives the correspondence $(i) \wedge (ii)$ the surjective property
$$ (\forall n \in N)(\exists m \in M) \: n \text{ corresponds to } m. $$